# Change submit button to close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit, formclosing

**How can i change behaviour of button if form submit was successful?**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin: 0;" id="frmGenerate">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Name:" name="CustomerName">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Generated Url:" name="CustomerUrl" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix">
         <div class="input-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn">Generate</button>
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
 $('#frmGenerate').submit(function(e) {
        var clientName = $(this).find('input[name="CustomerName"]').val();
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("GenerateToken","Admin")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { customerName: clientName },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.result) {
                        $('#frmGenerate').find('input[name="CustomerUrl"]').val(response.message).select();
                        $('#frmGenerate').find('button.btn').text('Close');
                    } else {
                        alert(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This is modal windows, which i open to generate token. When it's generated successful then i set generated token in modal input and change text of button to close, but i don't know how to change button's behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by button's behaviour? Can you give me the detail? What do you want the button to do?

Comment: @Mahder, i want use button on modal window firstle for submit form and then when submit was successful just close modal window onclick by the same button. Here is workaround like use 2 buttons (one for submit, second for close, just switch them). But if there any chanse to use 1 button for 2 options, if you understand what i mean. Thanks

Comment: i would suggest hide this button using $(".btn[type='submit']").hide() and create another button for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach would be not to change existing button, but *hide* it and *show* another.

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Generate</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-close hide">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#frmGenerate').find('.btn').hide();
$('#frmGenerate').find('.btn-close').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, i know about this solution, if you thinks this is better, then i would use it)

Comment: It's better because you have more flexibility. You can easily have different styles. Javascript code is not mixed with representation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of button you are using. Button must be used like: `<button></button>` Not like `<button/>`

And then use:

```
 $(".btn").html('Close');
```

Comment: i use `<button></button>`

Answer (score 0):

you can change attribute of button

```
 $('#frmGenerate').find('button.btn').attr('type', 'button');
```

and then:

```
$('#frmGenerate').find('button.btn').on('click', function(){ /*close function */});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have changed the text of your button to 'Close' after the form has been submitted. So the remaining part is the jQuery that handles a click event on the button.

....

```
     $('.btn').click(function(){
         var buttonText = $(this).val();
         if(buttonText === 'Close'){
         //code when close button is clicked
         }else if(buttonText === 'Generate'){
            //code when Generate button is clicked...
         }
      });//end button.click function
```

And I would use input type='button' or button than input type='submit'. Why dont you submit form using ajax as well? much better.

Hope this helps...